# How to efficiently Get Successor in HashTable?

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to write a function that gets the data associated with the successor key of a key passed as an argument. I want to write it to perform the operation as simply as possible, and apart from getting some errors so far, I'd like some advice on how to fix my code so it does so. The method I want advice on is GetSuccessor(Comparable key).

```
class HashTable
{
    int size;
    int length;
    Node nodes[];

    // Constants
    static final double max_load_factor = 0.7;
    static final int initial_size = 5;

    public HashTable()
    {
        size = initial_size;
        nodes = new Node[size];
    }

    // Return the data associated with the given key, or null if the key
    // is not present in the hash table.
    public Object Search(Comparable key)
    {
        // Obtain index for the key
        int index = key.hashCode() % size;

        // Traverse collision list
        for (Node node = nodes[index]; node != null; node = node.next)
            if (node.key.equals(key))
                return node.data;

        // Not found
        return null; 
    }

    // Insert a pair key-data into the hash table
    public void Insert(Comparable key, Object data)
    {
        // Check if the table must grow
        double load_factor = (double) length / size;        
        if (load_factor > max_load_factor)
            Grow();

        // Create node
        Node node = new Node(key, data);

        // Get index for the key
        int index = key.hashCode() % size;

        // Insert node
        node.next = nodes[index];
        nodes[index] = node;

        //Update length
        length++;
    }

    // Grow the hash table. All node must be repositioned according
    // to their new flash indices based on the new table.
    void Grow()
    {
        // Message
        System.out.println("Growing hash table");

        // Save old nodes and table siz4
        int old_size = size;
        Node[] old_nodes = nodes;   

        // Create new table
        size = size * 2;
        length = 0;
        nodes = new Node[size];

        // Traverse old nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < old_size; i++)
            for (Node node = old_nodes[i]; node != null; node = node.next)
                Insert(node.key, node.data);
    }

    // Return the data associated with the successor for the given key,
    // or null if the key is the last or it is not present.
    public Object GetSuccessor(Comparable key)
    {
        // Find node
        Node node = Search(key);
        if (node == null)
            return null;

        // Get sucessor node    
        for (Node node = nodes[key.hashCode()]; node != null; node = node.next)
            if (node.key.equals(key))
                return node.next.data;

        // Return associated data
        return node == null ? null : node.next.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hashtables are unordered. It follows that there is no such thing as a successor. If you want order and successors use an ordered map: `TreeMap`.

Comment: What I meant was the data associated with key 13 if 12 is passed as an argument

Comment: I understood what you meant; I have already shown that it is meaningless; and I have provided an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

first observation: when you run this it should produce an error when you initialize node to equal the result from Search(key). If you change it so that node= new Node(key, Search(key)) you'll move on to find an arrayindexoutofbounds exception. if you're in Ubal's 1:30 class check your email